# How to show survey question from database in html template?

Tags: javascript, arrays, backend

so i have an html template and i want to show a question, but the question is in the backend, so my question is how can i make the question show in my html template and make that automatically with JavaScript so every time the question changes in the backend its change in my template?

I did try to call the id of the div but that is not working.

Comment: One options is to fetch the data from the backend API (with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for example), and then replace the text of your element with [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). There are more options but it really depends on what is your end goal. You can look for more robust framworks for that case like React, Angular, Vue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.